# How do I add an event listener on position of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a css property of a div to change when a sibling div hits the top of the viewport.

Specifically I would like the "second-subdiv" to have `overflow: scroll` only when the "first-subdiv" hits the top of the viewport.

Basically I would like to set `overflow: hidden` on the "second-subdiv" and then write a couple of lines of js in which I would say:

`add.EventListener(when-first-subdiv-is-on-top, change the overflow property)`

```html
<div class="first-div">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>

<div class= "second-div">
  <div class="first subdiv">
    <h1>You are Beautiful</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="second subdiv">
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
    <h2>Something Good</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.first-div {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  h1 {
    color: white;
  }
}
.second-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.subdiv {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.first.subdiv {
  background-color: magenta;
}
.second.subdiv {

}
```

Any help with that?

Thanks,

Matteo

Comment: Check out the Intersection Observer API, where you can fire callbacks when elements enter or exit the viewport: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first define a function that implements the required styling logic.

```
const EPSILON = 0.5;

function setOverflow () {
  var firstDiv = document.querySelector('.first.subdiv');
  var secondDiv = document.querySelector('.second.subdiv');
  var rect = firstDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (Math.abs(rect.top) < EPSILON) {
    secondDiv.style.overflow = 'scroll';
  }
  else {
    secondDiv.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

The function `setOverflow` will read the position of the `.first.subdiv`, using [get​Bounding​Client​Rect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), and check if its `top`-coordinate is close enough to zero (i.e., the window’s top border) and set the overflow style property accordingly. As the `top`-coordinate will not usually be *exactly 0*, the tolerance for *close enough to 0* is defined to be between -0.5 and 0.5, by the `EPSILON` variable.

This function has to run whenever the position of the `.first.subdiv` element changes, such that the overflow property can be recalculated. You will need at least these events: `load`, `resize`, `scroll`, but you may need more depending on your final result. For example, if images are added dynamically, the position of the `.first.subdiv` may change without any of the above events triggering. You may want to look into the suggestion of [Dale Harris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2793460/dale-harris) and opt for the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

To avoid recalculating the overflow too many times, wrap the function call in a [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

```
function maybeSetOverflow () {
  if (!setOverflow.isBusy) {
    setOverflow.isBusy = true;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {setOverflow.isBusy = false; setOverflow()});
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', maybeSetOverflow);
window.addEventListener('resize', maybeSetOverflow);
window.addEventListener('load'  , maybeSetOverflow);
```

The function `maybeSetOverflow` will ignore duplicate calls to setOverflow, if it has already been called, but not executed in the animation frame.

Just wrap both of these code parts in a `<script>` and put it at the bottom of your `<body>`.